# How to write the component information on the top of it with an arrow in the bottom using Circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows, circuitikz

In fact I want to make a little change on my circuit that I drew using Circuitikz.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{lscape,array}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5][american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
\draw

(0,0) to [open,v>=${v}_{ds}$] (0,5) 
to [short, *- ,i=${i}_{ds}$] (0.3,5)
to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,5) 
to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.2,5)
to [european voltage source, l_=${\omega}_s {\phi}_{qs}$] (4.9,5)
(4.5,5) to [short, -] (5,5)
(5,5) to [L, l_=$X_m$] (5,0)

(5,5) to [european voltage source, l_=${\omega}_r {\phi}_{qr}$] (7,5)
to [L, l=$X_r$] (8,5)
to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,5)
to [short, -* ,i<=${i}_{dr}$] (10.3,5) 
(10.3,0) to [open, v>=${v}_{dr}$] (10.3,5)
(0,0) to [short, *-*] (10.3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

To be more accurate here is what I want to do after compiling:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it is not very clear what you want to achieve. As far as I understood it, and if you want this:
[image]
then you should use this code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{lscape,array}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5][american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
\draw

(0,0) to [open,v>=$v_{ds}$] (0,5) 
to [short, *- ,i=$i_{ds}$] (0.3,5)
to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,5) 
to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.2,5)
to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_s \phi_{qs}$] (4.9,5)
(4.5,5) to [short, -] (5,5)
(5,5) to [L, l_=$X_m$] (5,0)


(5,5) to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_r \phi_{qr}$] (7,5)
to [L, l=$X_r$] (8,5)
to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,5)
to [short, -* ,i<=$i_{dr}$] (10.3,5) 
(10.3,0) to [open, v>=$v_{dr}$] (10.3,5)
(0,0) to [short, *-*] (10.3,0);
\draw[->](3.5,4.3) -- (4.9,4.3);
\draw[->](6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want but for Arrows I want them in Black and in the place where was the omega {\phi} to indicate their sens

Comment: I changed the code for you.
You can play with color, thickness and exact coordinates.

Comment: Plus, you don't need so many `{`'s and `}`'s. `\omega_r` works just fine as `{\omega}_r`

Comment: Please bmv I want the arrow to have triangular head in black as the arrows in the voltages how can I do it ?

Comment: Write `\draw[-latex](6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);` in line 32 of my code (instead of `\draw[->](6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);`).